# Returning specific key(s) and its value from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, find, key

I'm writing a function where I need to analyze a dictionary and pull out one of the keys and all of its values and return it.

Example dictionary:

```
{'P':[("Eight",1460, 225.0, 200.0, "fresco","Netherlands"),
      ("Six",1465,81.0, 127.1, "tempera", "Netherlands")],
 'V':[("Four",1661, 148.0, 257.0,"oil paint", "Austria"),
      ("Two",1630, 91.0, 77.0, "oil paint","USA")],
 'K':[("Five",1922,63.8,48.1,"watercolor","USA"),
      ("Seven",1950,61.0,61.0,"acrylic paint","USA"),
      ("Two",1965,81.3,100.3,"oil paint","United Kingdom")],
 'C':[("Ten",1496,365.0,389.0,"tempera","Italy")],
 'U':[("Nine",1203,182.0, 957.0,"egg tempera","Italy"),
      ("Twelve",1200,76.2,101.6,"egg tempera","France")]}
```

So if my function is called find_the_key and I was looking for 'C' and its value then it would need to return

```
find_the_key(dictionary2(),['C'])

return {'C': [('Ten', 1496, 365.0, 389.0, 'tempera','Italy')]}
```

If it needed to find both 'C' and 'V' it would return

```
find_the_key(dictionary2(),['C','V'])

return {'C': [('Ten', 1496, 365.0, 389.0, 'tempera', 'Italy')], 'V': [('Four',
1661, 148.0, 257.0, 'oil paint', 'Austria'), ('Two', 1630, 91.0, 77.0, 'oil
paint', 'USA')]}
```

I've done some research on extracting a key from a dictionary and my current code could be close.

```
def find_the_key(dictionary,thekey):
    for thekey in dictionary.keys():
      if dictionary[thekey] == targetkey:
        return key, targetkey
```

Currently I'm getting the error targetkey is not defined though I think my logic is on the right track. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do if a key doesn't exist in the dictionary? Just ignore it, raise an error, or return a default value?

Comment: @PM2Ring Jean-François Fabre's solution does the correct thing which I believe is just ignoring it

Comment: I believe both answers handle the problem without even noticing it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways of doing it:

1) loop on input dictionary items scan the key in the key list each time, okay but doesn't use the fact that the input is a dictionary. If the key list or the input dictionary is very long it can take time (improve it slightly by turning key list into a `set` maybe)

```
def find_the_key(dictionary,thekey):
    return {k:v for k,v in dictionary.items() if k in thekey}
```

2) do the loop not in the dictionary, but in the asked keys, more logical and faster if the key list & the dictionary are big

```
def find_the_key(dictionary,thekey):
    return {k:dictionary[k] for k in thekey if k in dictionary}
```

Small drawback: test if `k` belongs and then get `dictionary[k]`, which hashes `k` twice

3) classical, no listcomp, but only 1 access to the dictionary using `get`

```
def find_the_key(dictionary,thekey):
    d={}

    for k in thekey:
        v = dictionary.get(k)
        if k:
            d[k]=v
    return d
```

of course all methods yield the same results

Comment: In your last version, you need `if v:` instead of `if k:`

Comment: Thanks I've given you best answer because all your answers worked well and you also helped me figure out another function I was having trouble with

Answer (score 2):

```
def find_the_key(dictionary, target_keys):
    return {key: dictionary[key] for key in target_keys}
```

This uses a dictionary comprehension, which is just a convenient way to build up a dictionary. What you were doing (after fixing variable names) would only return a single pair (a tuple) of key and value. If you return from a loop, you only return that one thing: the loop doesn't continue and simultaneously return all the other similar things.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response this accomplishes my goal

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using `filter` function:

*I've intentionally passed an improper key `J` within `filter_keys` to handle different cases*

```
def find_the_key(dictionary, filter_keys):
    return dict(filter(lambda  i: i[0] in filter_keys, dictionary.items()))

print(find_the_key(dictionary, ['C','V','J']))
```

The output:

```
{'C': [('Ten', 1496, 365.0, 389.0, 'tempera', 'Italy')], 'V': [('Four', 1661, 148.0, 257.0, 'oil paint', 'Austria'), ('Two', 1630, 91.0, 77.0, 'oil paint', 'USA')]}
```